# Hibernate/JPA : Remove from multiple parents when child is deleted

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, one-to-many

I have a specific issue that I don't know if Hibernate can automatically resolve:

In our domain model, we have many bidirectional One-to-many relationships, where the "child" might be a child of many parents.

Example:

```
public Class Role {

    @ManyToOne(targetEntity = Actor.class, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private Actor actor;

    @ManyToOne(targetEntity = Contact.class, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private Contact contact;
}

public class Actor {

    @OneToMany(targetEntity = Role.class, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private List<Role> roles;
} 
public class Contact {

    @OneToMany(targetEntity = Role.class, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private List<Role> roles;
}
```

The question I have, is that when removing a Role - node by calling `entityManager.remove(node)`, I simultaneously want to remove the Role -refrence from all the mapped lists so that the db fields gets nulled appropriately, while KEEPING the parents and not calling remove on their respective Lists

Is this possible, or is this the default behaviour of jpa/hibernate?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you should explicitly iterate the contact and actor object's role lists and remove the appropriate role object. That is the only option. Because it wont remove automatically sometime (Most of the time).

Comment: Yeah, the domain model sometimes uses a foreign key or a reference in the database on each side of the relation, and sometimes just on one side of the relation. Most reliable way was to explicitly iterate over the collection, and that was confirmed by unit testing the code.

Answer (score 1):

I daresaay this will happen automagically. Actor and contact lists  are build on foreign keys inside role object -   if role is removed from db then it will dissapear  from collections when Role/Contact are loaded in another session.   Actually parent objects do not hold any reference in them to the Role.

Comment: I think it depends on how it is declared. You could only have the relation OneToMany which generate a relation table instead of adding a column to set the reference.